# PHPdoc: Documenting chainable methods?

Tags: php, oop, documentation, phpdoc

How should I properly use PHPdoc to document chainable methods in a class, as seen in the below example - what is the correct usage?

```
class myClass {


    /**
    * @return myClass
    */
    function one()
    {
        return $this;
    }

    /**
    * @return self
    */
    function two()
    {
        return $this;
    }

    /**
    * @return $this
    */
    function three()
    {
        return $this;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
/**
* @return myClass
*/
```

I'm not a phpDoc expert but's that's how they do it in Zend framework. So I think it's reliable

Comment: This option tends to work best, especially with IDE autocompletion.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer

```
/**
* @return $this
*/
```

Comment: Well is that *supported* by PHPDoc? That's merely runtime, not static code documentation in my eyes.